# Set the desired date format to file name in Python

Tags: python, datetime

I want to specify the date of the desired format as a file name in this way
;

During [2019-10-01 09:00 ~ 2019-10-02 08:59:59] 
Save data to 191001-09.txt

I have no idea about this. I could only follow simple code.
Please let me know how to fix it :

```
def timeStamped (fname, fmt = '19% m% d-% H {fname} '):
    return datetime.datetime.now (). strftime (fmt) .format (fname = fname)
with open (timeStamped ('. txt'), 'a') as f_last:
    f_last.write ('data')
```

Comment: This article would make things work [here.](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/datetime/strftime)

Comment: store this into string format and use regex expression.

Comment: Thanks for your link. but there seems to be no way to set a specific time range. It's too hard for me to have an application.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know the bypass method, but it's also difficult. I should think more. Thank you both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Question**: Conditional file name from `datetime.now()`

- Import the required objects

  - [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects)
  - [timedelta](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects)

  ```
  from datetime import datetime, timedelta
  ```
- Define a function that gets the desired file name from a `datetime.date` object:

  ```
  def fname_from_date(date):
      # Rule  09:00:00 ~ day + 1 08:59:59 
      midnight = date.replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0)
      begin_of_day = date.replace(hour=9, minute=0, second=0)
      end_of_day = date.replace(hour=8, minute=59, second=59)

      # Are we between 'midnight' and 'end_of_day'
      if date >= midnight and date <= end_of_day:
          date = date - timedelta(days=1)
          print('\tNext day -1: {}'.format(date))

      # 191001-09.txt
      fname = date.strftime('%Y%m%d-09')
      return fname
  ```
- Test the function `def fname_from_date(...` with static dates.
  This requires to create a `datetime.date` object from `datestr`.

  ```
  for datestr in ['2019-10-01 09:00:00', 
                  '2019-10-01 11:01:11', 
                  '2019-10-02 07:07:07', 
                  '2019-10-02 08:59:59']:
      date = datetime.strptime(datestr, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
      print(date)
      fname = '{}.txt'.format(fname_from_date(date))
      print('\t{}'.format(fname))
  ```

  > **Output**:
  >
  > ```
  > 2019-10-01 09:00:00
  >     20191001-09.txt
  > 2019-10-01 11:01:11
  >     20191001-09.txt
  > 2019-10-02 07:07:07
  >     Next day -1: 2019-10-01 07:07:07
  >     20191001-09.txt
  > 2019-10-02 08:59:59
  >     Next day -1: 2019-10-01 08:59:59
  >     20191001-09.txt
  > ```

> **Usage**:

```
fname = '{}.txt'.format(fname_from_date(datetime.now()))
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll give it a try.